# Where did it go? sudo su then mv a.zip ~/desktop

Tags: macos, terminal, root

I elevated to root user with `sudo su` then I made the mistake of trying to move a file to my logged in profile's desktop with `mv a.zip ~/desktop`. As a result, I am unable to locate the `a.zip` file. I tried searching the file system through the GUI. Moreover while still elevated as root the `cd ~/desktop` command says location does not exist.

Where is `a.zip` now? This occurred in OSX operating system, v10.11 I believe.

Comment: `sudo su` again, then `cd ~/` and then `ls`.  My suspicion is that you have a new file called desktop that looks like your zip.

Comment: @Mokubai I found it there as you said and I was able to recover its contents. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It most likely went to `/root/desktop/a.zip` or `/root/desktop` (if `/root/desktop` does not exist as a directory)

Once you ran `sudo su`, you became root entirely, and root's home is `/root`.

Edit: I see you are using OSX, under OSX root's home is usually `/var/root/`, so look for `/var/root/desktop/a.zip` or `/var/root/desktop`

Comment: In this case, the location `~/` was the same as `/var/root` and the way I used the `mv` command caused the file to be renamed to `desktop`. I was able to restore the file by moving it to a proper location and giving it back its .zip extension.